# C# Переход по формам и их закрытие

Tags: c#, winforms

В программе существует несколько форм.

Из главной формы вызываются другие по кнопкам вроде такой схемы

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Но при нажатии на стандартный крестик для закрытия программы побочных форм, программа не выключается насовсем.

Её процесс всё ещё лежит в диспетчере.

Метод `Application.Exit();` также кладёт программу не полностью.

Может быть кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: Вы запускаете программу форму в основном потоке , далее из этого потока запускаете другие потоки , или формы - мы здесь должны угадать как реализован запуск других форм, и в конце концов на какой крестик вы нажимаете ? в 100500 форме в потоке 25 го поколения ?

Comment: @DigitalCore, исправил

Comment: То есть вы спрятав основную форму , открываете новую форму, после закрытия которой вы хотите чтоб приложение завершило работу ?

Comment: @eriksongerson попробуй свои создаваемые формы, после работы с ними, уничтожать через [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx). Вообще, проблема с неполным закрытием есть и даже описана на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx). Там собственно советуют вызвать Dispose.

Comment: @DigitalCore,я хочу, чтобы приложение завершало свою работу при всех закрытых формах, а не только главной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
Form frm = new Form2();
this.Hide();
if (frm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    Close();
```